# How to create Icon component for component library based on @heroicons?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, heroicons

I want to create a component which can be used as

```
<Icon name="XMarkIcon" variant="solid" />
```

and base on @heroicons https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons library.
I started with this code, my issues are:

1. How to create type for all available icon names from @heroicons package like 'Icon1' | 'Icon2' | 'Icon3' ... 'IconX'
2. How to find icons based on icon name, because now I can pick up an icon by doing <IconsSolid.XMarkIcon />
   I would appreciate any help, thank you! :)

```
export * as IconsSolid from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'
export * as IconsOutline from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'

interface ButtonProps extends React.SVGAttributes<SVGElement> {
  name: ??? <<<--- How to provide all icon names here from the @herolist package?
  variant: 'solid' | 'outline'
}

export const Button = ({
  name,
  variant,
  ...rest
}: ButtonProps) => {
  const { className, ...props } = rest

  if (variant === 'solid') {
    return (
      <IconsSolid ... /> <<<--- How to pick up an icon based on the its name (string)?
    )
  }
  if (variant === 'outline') {
    return (
      <IconsOutline ... />
    )
  }
  return null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (note that it's only the solid icons but can easily be extended).

Using ComponentProps to just expose all props already on the Heroicons,

```
import * as HeroIcon from '@heroicons/react/20/solid'
import { ComponentProps } from 'react'

type Props = {
  name: keyof typeof HeroIcon
} & ComponentProps<typeof HeroIcon.AcademicCapIcon>

const Icon = ({ name, ...props }: Props) => {
  const IconComponent = HeroIcon[name]
  return <IconComponent {...props} />
}

const ExampleUse = () => (
  <Icon name="ArrowDownIcon" className="size-6 text-primary" />
)
```